# apache storm on cent os 7

Tags: centos, apache-storm

We are having issues installing storm on cent os 7

```
File "./storm", line 514, in <module>
  main()
File "./storm", line 511, in main
  (COMMANDS.get(COMMAND, unknown_command))(*ARGS)
File "./storm", line 308, in nimbus
  jvmopts = parse_args(confvalue("nimbus.childopts", cppaths)) + [
File "./storm", line 113, in confvalue
  p = sub.Popen(command, stdout=sub.PIPE)
File "/root/Installers/Python-2.7.8/Lib/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
File "/root/Installers/Python-2.7.8/Lib/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: do you have python installed in the same box?

Comment: yes we have installed in the same box

Comment: Can you precise all the versions implied?

Comment: what is the python version ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with java path.Once that was changed it was resolved.

best
vj